# Google Charts y-axis values

Tags: python, charts, google-visualization

I have a set of paired data:

```
[(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3, y_3)]
```

and I want to make an `XYChart` out of it using the python [`GChartWrapper`](https://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/) library such that that the y-axis values are a transformation of the data.

A simple example is a log graph with the actual values on the side, *e.g.* if `y_1`, `y_2`, and `y_3` represent `log_10` values, then the graph will chart them as such but the labels on the y-axis could be `10^{y_1}`, `10^{y_2}`, and `10^{y_3}`.

I've tried playing around with `chxr` for this but that doesn't work because then it's not just the labels on the axis that change, but the whole axis. For example, if I have the log one from above and my y values are `0`, `1`, `2`. I would like the graph to look the same but the labels to instead be `10^0`, `10^1`, `10^2`, *i.e.* `1`, `10`, `100`. But because the gchart wants to preserve the scale, it then tries to make this into something where the range is from `0 -> 100` rather than just changing the labels.

How do I do this?

Comment: Aye. Thanks for the heads up on some older ones that I hadn't seen the answers to.

Comment: It might help to include some example output; see [this SO question about Google Charts and GChartWrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850561/google-chart-api-trouble-with-rendering-a-xyline-graph).

Comment: On a minor point, `10^0 = 1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `chxl` to change the labels of the axis but not the range. [API chxl](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#axis_labels)